# Bootstrap popover, image as content

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, popover

I'm trying to this:

```
$("a[rel=popover]").popover({
    html:       true,
    trigger:    'hover',
    content:    '<img src="'+$(this).data('img')+'" />'
});
```

but it doesn't work because the $(this).data('img') doesn't work.

Why I do this, I've got conflicts with templating and html in the data-content attribute. So I place the image source in a data-img attribue and like to grab that en place it into a img element.

I've tried this, but works not fully:

```
$("a[rel=popover_img]").popover({
    html:       true,
    trigger:    'hover',
    content:    '<img src="#" id="popover_img" />'
}).hover(function(){
    $('#popover_img').attr('src',$(this).data('img'));
});
```

I hope somebody can help me out :)

Answer (score 65, accepted):

As it currently stands your `this` is referencing the current scope, whereas you want to be referencing the element which the Popover instance is attached to.  This is done simply by wrapping the expression you have for `content` in a function:

```
$('a[rel=popover]').popover({
  html: true,
  trigger: 'hover',
  content: function () {
    return '<img src="'+$(this).data('img') + '" />';
  }
});
```

See demo:

### [Plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/nhlFPz)

Comment: Is a popover limitation when i tried to show a bigger image? like 500x500px, the popover border did not surrounded the image.

Comment: @Khrys Yes. Bootstrap has the default: `.popover { max-width: 276px; }`. However, it also has `img { width: 100%; }` which should scale the popover content accordingly. The problem you described must be coming from conflicting CSS, or customizations.

Comment: @merv, in the example you posted in Plunker the first image has 400x200, but the popover isn't allowing it to be at this resolution... the side image is 200x100 and shows as the same visual size. Should the first one be visually bigger? thx

Comment: @Khrys The `width: 100%` CSS indicates that the width of the image should be scaled to fit its parent container. So, no, it shouldn't be bigger; it's behaving as designed.

Comment: For me the images took a second to fall in place and this caused the popover to do weird things. Setting a fixed height helped me       `$('a[rel=image-popover]').popover({
        html: true,
        trigger: 'hover',
        placement: 'top',
        content: function(){return '<img src="'+$(this).data('img') + '" />';}
      }).on("show.bs.popover", function() {
        return $(this).data("bs.popover").tip().css({
          height: "280px"
        });
      });`

Comment: the images are not appearing for me in the demo plunker

Answer (score 12):

An alternative to what merv proposed, for simplicity you can embed a lot of the jquery properties to the html and leave the jquery lightweighted e.g

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover Header" data-html="true" data-content="<img src='http://localhost:15249/img1.jpg' width='200' />">Toggle popover</a>
```

and call the popover via jquery

```
$('["popover"]').popover()
```

Points to note when using this approach, the data-html should be set to true, else the image is not interpreted as html but as text

Answer (score 2):

try this

[html]

```
<a href="#"><i class="menu-icon fa fa-picture-o fa-3x" data-rel="popover" title="<strong>Hi, I'm Popover</strong>" data-placement="top" data-content="<img src='https://www.google.co.id/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png' width=50% height=50%>"></i></a>
```

[javascript]

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('[data-rel=popover]').popover({
  html: true,
  trigger: "hover"
});
```

})

[check this out]
https://jsfiddle.net/j4qptkzr/20/