# bootstrap popover to display image

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using a bootstrap popover to display images but it just does not seem to work. The title of the movie is being displayed on popover but not the image of the movie. Please Help !

```
 $.ajax({

            url: "http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies.json?apikey=XXXX&q=" + name + "&page_limit=5",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            success: function (response) {
                $(".display-movie").empty();
                var ul = $(".display-movie");
                console.log(response);
                for (var i = 0; i < response.movies.length; i++) {

                    var img = $("<img>").attr("src", response.movies[i].posters.thumbnail)
                                     .css({
                                         width: 200,
                                         height: 200,
                                         margin: 20
                                     }).append(aend);

                    var astart = $("<a>", {
                        href: '#',
                        rel: 'popover',
                        title : response.movies[i].title,
                    }).append(img);

                    var aend = $("</a>");
                    var div = $("<div></div>")
                        .append(astart)
                        .append(response.movies[i].title);
                    $("<li></li>")
                        .append(div)
                        .appendTo(ul);


                    var popoverimg = '<img src = "' + response.movies[i].posters.thumbnail + '"/>';
                    $(".display-movie").popover({
                        title : response.movies[i].title,
                        content: popoverimg,
                        html : true
                    });
                }
            }
        });
```

In html i have : ul class="display-movie"

Comment: If you add your html and css it is easier to help. If you provide a codepen.io  or a plnkr.co you increase your chances to get an answer.

Comment: Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13604144/bootstrap-popover-image-as-content