# Bootstrap image in popover without re-downloading the image

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am downloading and re-sizing an image to fit into my design (reduce width/height). If I want to create a popover on hover of the full image do I have to re-download the image again? Since this answer suggests that way: [Bootstrap popover, image as content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13604144/bootstrap-popover-image-as-content).

My `jade` looks like this:

```
img#art.img-responsive(style='margin-bottom:10%')
```

And I update the source of the image whenever I need with the following code:

```
   if (questionMap[questionOrder[number - 1]].type === 'ART') {
        $('#art').attr('src', 'http://' + questions.host + '/image/' + questionMap[questionOrder[number - 1]].src)
    }
```

Now do I need to add to the popover code the same source attribute and make download it the second time or there is another workaround? From another perspective: if I include twice the same image in a page does it get's downloaded two times (assuming server side caching is enabled)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browsers are pretty smart when it comes to caching.It should only ask for it once.

Additionally when it asks the server for an image, it usually sends with the request for the image, a couple of headers that tell the server.. Hey, I want this image, but I got one already that has these attributes that you told me about it last time you sent it to me.

The server can then respond with a 200 meaning it's different content 304 meaning the one you have is the same, so I won't send it again, use the one you got..

Browser will cache it. Depending on the user's setting however, the browser may request the image again the next time the page is requested, like for example, if the user clears their cache between page visits.