# display image on hover a sql value in php

Tags: php

I have a script:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({   
          trigger:'hover',
          html:true
       });
    });
</script>
```

then, verify every value from foto column

```
if($foto[$j]){
    echo('<a href="#" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" title="Produse" data-content="<img src="images/foto/produse/'.$foto[$j].'" alt="Produse" style="width:604px;height:428px;"><td>'.$nume[$j].'</td> '); 
}else{
    echo('<td>'.$nume[$j].'</td> ');
}
```

if i find value for `$foto[$j]`, add link for name product, else display name product without link.

What wrong with my code?

SOLUTION (the quotes were the problem)

```
echo('<td><a href="'.$foto[$j].'" class="link" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" title="'.$nume[$j].'" data-content="<img src=\''.$foto[$j].'\' alt=\'Grafic realizari\' style=\'width:250px;height:200px;\'>">'.$nume[$j].'</a></td> ');
```

Comment: check the console for the errors you are getting.

Comment: check out this [link](http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=faq&file=display-image-inside-bootstrap-popover) or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13612185/3202287), is in static accordingly change it dynamic one

Comment: Did you check if the html is getting generated properly?

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't your php, it's your html. You are trying to put an `<a>` tag *outside* the `<td>` tag, and you are not closing it.

Do this instead:

```
echo('<td><a href="#" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" title="Produse" data-content="<img src="images/foto/produse/'.$foto[$j].'" alt="Produse" style="width:604px;height:428px;">'.$nume[$j].'</a></td> ');
```

Comment: @ElenaIvan Again, this is almost certainly an html issue. Check that your html is correct.