# How to place images on popovers or tool-tip in a webpage?

Tags: html, css, html5-canvas

I am trying to insert images on popovers. I mean, when a user hovers on a text, an image should appear.

How to do this. Please solve this.

Comment: Make a popover layer but instead of text place an image. You can look here: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13604144/bootstrap-popover-image-as-content)

Answer (score 0):

https://tutsme-webdesign.info/bootstrap-3-popover-with-image/

Visit the said link,it provides the working solutions regarding popover.